# My objects keep showing up as null in Thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf, java-ee-8

I'm trying to learn how to integrate Spring MVC and Thymeleaf with Java EE 8. I'm able to get the server running, and the template does show when I visit the server (localhost:8080/[name of my war exploded] (which I also want to figure out how to change and just have my index appear at localhost:8080).

However, when I visit the page in the browser the value where my object should be (currentDate in the controller) always appears as null no matter the data type of the object, whether String or Integer, Date, anything.

I don't want to use Spring Boot. I need to use Spring MVC and Thymeleaf within the Java EE 8 project structure. I know from seeing the other text on the html page that the server is able to locate my template. Just not sure why the data keeps appearing as null.

Any help would be appreciated.

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.github.kyleryxn</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jakarta-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-mvc-thymeleaf-jakarta-demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ****** Java Compile/Runtime Dependencies ****** -->
        <!-- ******************* Logging ******************* -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ******************* Others ******************* -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ********* Servlet & MVC Dependencies ********* -->
        <!-- **************** Java Servlet **************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ***************** Spring MVC ***************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ***************** Thymeleaf ****************** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ************* Testing Dependencies *********** -->
        <!-- ******************** JUnit ******************* -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>My Spring MVC Thymeleaf App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p th:text="'Current Date: ' + ${currentDate}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller class:

```java
package com.github.kyleryxn.springmvcthymeleafjakartademo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/index/test")
    public String hello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("currentDate", String.valueOf(90));

        // Return name of Thymeleaf template
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Thymeleaf config class

```java
package com.github.kyleryxn.springmvcthymeleafjakartademo.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode;

@Configuration
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

Spring config class

```java
package com.github.kyleryxn.springmvcthymeleafjakartademo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

mvc-servlet.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.github.kyleryxn.springmvcthymeleafjakartademo"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1"
>
    <display-name>Spring MVC XML Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring root -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.github.kyleryxn.springmvcthymeleafjakartademo</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Spring child -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- additional config -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: And why not Spring Boot? Version 2.7 is perfectly JEE8 capable and does what you want automatically without you having to reinvent the wheel. That being said, your model is empty and thus `null`. You configured the `/` to render the `index.html` page. This is done without invoking the controller so nothing is added to the model.

Comment: Because I'm already working with an existing project that doesn't utilize Spring Boot